PHP pg_send_query_params passing int[] or string[] parameter for IN ($1)
Struggling a while with passing an array parameter for a simple Redshift (Postgres8) query like this:
// Example: 
$sql = "select * from country where country_code IN ($1) LIMIT 10";
$params = ["'GB','US'"];

pg_send_query_params($conn, $sql, $params);

Redshift engine does not care about any "array" format I'm trying to pass
the same happens for integer[]
I've been trying passings parameters in a various ways like
"'GB','US'"
"{'GB','US'}"
"['GB','US']"
"('GB','US')"
"ARRAY['GB','US']"
// etc...

I've been also trying with cast operator for the parameter like
IN ($1::text[])
None of those work as expected

Use =ANY() instead of IN(). That takes an array as input as solves your problem.

As @FrankHeikens commented, use =any().
$sql = 'select * from country where country_code = any($1::text[]) LIMIT 10';
$params = ['{GB,US}'];

or
$sql = 'select * from country where country_code = any((\'{\'||$1||\'}\')::text[]) LIMIT 10';
$params = ['GB,US'];

Unrelated but it is highly recommended to use PDO instead of pg_* set of functions.

Don't agree with the comment about PDO, the standard pg_*-function offer much more functionality that is easier to use than PDO. Best example is pg_put_line for high performance import of CSV content into tables, not even possible in PDO. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-put-line.php

The reason I didn't want to use PDO is because of synchronous queries. In my case I wanted to start multiple queries at the same time and await for all of them to finish. I've made a custom connection pool with a custom connection wrapper and this is why pg_* set of functions was my choice.

@FrankHeikens Fair enough, especially the pg_send_*  is a breath of fresh air. I missed that until now.
